# Given a stream of random numbers try to find numbers that are evenly spaced

Tags: python, arrays, numbers

#### Problem:

I have a stream of numbers that are not evenly spaced as inputs and I need to find a sequence of numbers using the one above that return as many number as possible for the first sequence, but evenly spaced.

#### Example:

```
stream = [1,4,9,11,12,17,18,25,30,33,34,41,44,49,57,65,73,81,89,90,97,100]
```

I need to find a sequence that contains as many numbers as possible that are evenly separated

For instance I know that I can find:

> 1,9,17,25,33,41,49,57,65,75,81,89,97

that are all separated by 8.

How do I solve this problem in general?

Comment: @Taegyung: That question presupposes a subsequence (a contiguous run of numbers); in this question, there are intervening elements.

Comment: Is it a stream (as in infinite source) or just a finite sequence (as in a list or 1d array)? If it is an infinite source, and if the numbers are truly random, there are infinite number of answers -- you will be able to find evenly spaced sequences of every possible step-size. On the other hand, if it is just a finite list, the fact that the numbers are "random" probably becomes irrelevant to your requirement.

Comment: It seems pretty clear to me from his example what he's talking about.  I expect that by "random", he means "arbitrary".

Answer (score 0):

```
def find_seq(lst):
    running = []
    done = []
    so_far = []
    for element in sorted(lst):
        still_running = []
        for run in running:
            d, m = divmod(element - run[0], run[2])
            if m == 0:
                if d == run[1]:
                    run[1] += 1
                    still_running.append(run)
                else:
                    done.append(run)
            else:
                still_running.append(run)
        running = still_running + [[previous, 2, element - previous] for previous in so_far]
        so_far.append(element)
    return max(done + running, key=lambda run: run[1])

start, length, step = find_seq([1,4,9,11,12,17,18,25,30,33,34,41,44,49,57,65,73,81,89,90,97,100])
```

For each pair of elements, we assume they start a sequence (with assumed length of 2 to begin with). For any new element, we check if it would fit into a sequence (or more) that we're tracking; if it would, but a value was skipped, the sequence is finished; otherwise, we increase the length of the sequence. All sequences will finish at the end of the input. Then it is an easy matter to see which sequence ran the longest.